# Enable webgl for Windows 8 running on ATI Legacy Drivers

Tags: windows-8, amd-radeon, display-driver

My Firefox 19 `about:support` shows me:

> Adapter description: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3670.
>
> Adapter drivers: aticfx64 aticfx64 aticfx32 aticfx32 atiumd64 atidxx64 atiumdag atidxx32 atiumdva atiumd6a atitmm64
>
> Direct2D enabled: blocked for your graphics card. try to upgrade to version > 12.8 or newer.
>
> GPU-accelerated windows: blocked for your graphicscard. try to upgrade to version > 12.8 or newer.
>
> WebGL-renderer: blocked for your graphicscard. try to upgrade to version > 12.8 or newer.

My platform is a dell xps16 (old) with Windows 8 x64.

I have installed the [latest (legacy) driver for the ATi Mobility Radeon HD 3670](http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/catalystlegacywin8.aspx) from the ATi website. But my device management in Windows tells me that I have this 8.970.100.3000 version from AMD.

In the `about:config` is `gfx.blacklist.direct2d` set to 3. (not by me! )

When I remove all ATI stuff, it uses **ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3670 (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM v1.1)** which is also fine, because it feels faster with the metro interface. But I also have the disabled direct2d and webgl in firefox.

when I open setup.exe from fresh downloaded `AMD_Catalyst_12.6_Legacy_Win8` I get this screen which will install version **8.970.100.3000** and the utility from the ati website also redirects me to the same download from the ati website as the manual selection does. sorry for the dutch screenshot.

[image: ati install screen]

Ps. Already rebooted the pc after the driver installation. And webgl is also not working with chrome 24.

Comment: The latest legacy drives are 12.6 - if you can't install the drivers then WebGL can't be enabled

Comment: I can install the driver, but it showed 8.970.100.3000 in windows device management

Comment: the installer skips driver install silently if the card isn't supported.

Comment: it does not skip it, just installs an 8.9x version??

Comment: AMD/ATi's Radeon versioning is confusing. 12.x are the version numbers of the Catalyst suite. The drivers are 8.xxxx. You need to check what version of drivers 12.6 & 12.8 provides, and check it against what you have